# Binary search in an array which has all but two elements are sorted,i.e all elements are sorted and then two adjacent elements swapped?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Is it possible to do a binary search in an array in which first all elements are sorted and after that  two adjacent elements(of the sorted array) are interchanged?

example
3  10 40 20 50 70 80

In this example 20 and 40 have been swapped.

Comment: Add some more tags, example c, c++, java like. If you mention language you can get immediate response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Binary search can be done on this type of array. Idea for this is something similar to binary search in rotated sorted array -https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-an-element-in-a-sorted-and-pivoted-array/

Suppose you need to search 40 in this --

- After 1st iteration { 3 10 40 20 50 70 80 } -> { 3 10 40 20} and {50 70 80}. 
  You will need to boundary conditions when you are dividing this array. In this case need to check if 40 does exists in 2nd sub array.
- 2nd Iteration . -> { 3 10 40 20} -> {3,10} {40,20}. 
  Same boundary condition needs to be applied in case of first subarray here.

Comment: How could you know that you need to search for 40? Looks like even you break it into 2 sub-array, you still need to search in both sub-arrays, so what is the time complexity here?

Comment: It was just an example. You can take any number, but array division will be similar. Also, you dont need to search in both arrays, just 2nd last element of 1st array and 2nd element of 2nd array. Complexity will be O(log n) only as all arrays are not getting searched.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense +1